# Do I need a transit visa in Australia?

Tags: transit-visas, australia

I'm travelling to Jordan and my itinerary mentions a technical stop in Australia. Will I need to apply for an Australian transit visa for this?

Comment: What is your citizenship?

Comment: What did the airline say when you asked them? A technical stop is usually a touch down by a flight for either technical reasons such as refuelling or to pick up and/or drop off passengers. If you’re booked to continue your journey you won’t disembark, and so typically don’t need a visa even if you would normally need one for the country where the stop is scheduled.

Comment: @Traveller I don't know about OZ, but I know some airports that require all passengers to disembark if the plane drops off and picks up passengers. Bangkok *used to* do it, Taipei still does.

Comment: I don’t see how the implications of the technical stop can be reliably answered by anyone other than the airline.